# JQ drag & drop - I can get the over event to fire but not the drop?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

So I have a list whose elements are listed as droppable.

When I try and drag a draggable over these elements, I can not get the drop function to fire.

However, if I add the over function to the droppable, it fires fine... I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
 $('#stepList').append('<li class=\"steps ui-state-highlight\" style=\"margin-top:10px;\" >' +
                     '<div class=\"close\"><span class=\"closeSpan ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close\">&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;</div>' +
                     '<div class=\"stepNum"></div>' +
                     '<div class=\"stepInfo">Step Type: <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"editInfo(' + newStepInfo.infoID + ')\">  ' + newStepInfo.typeOfStep + '</a></div>' +
                     '<div class=\"nameDiv\"></div>' +
                     '<div class=\"sigDiv\"></div> <div class=\"disDiv"\></div></li>');
    $('.close').bind('click', function () {
        killStep(this);
    });
    renumberSteps();

    //Adding the Droppable ability to this newest added STEP
    $("#stepList li:last").droppable({
        over: function (event, ui) { alert('testOver'); }, // addFunctionsToDropBox(this, event, ui); },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert('test');
            //Main function to bind all droppable events.
            //addFunctionsToDropBox(this, ev, ui);
        }
    });
```

My draggables are here:
 $(".option").draggable({ helper: "clone" });

HTML:

```
<div id="mainbox">
            <div id="dropbox">
                <ul id="stepList">
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="rightBar">
                <div class="newStep">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-person"></span>Add a step</div>

                <div id="nameBox" class="ui-state-hover option">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-flag" style="float: left; margin-right: -0.85em;"></span>
                    Name a step.
                    <input type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input" style="width: 95px;" id="stepName" />
                </div>

                  <div id="attachBox" class="ui-state-hover option">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-suitcase" style="float:left; margin-right: -0.85em;"></span>
                    Add attachment.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

These LI's sit in a div that is also a droppable, so I dont know if that could be messing anything up but I know I have been able to create this behavior before, just am having issues now.

Thanks for any help!
Todd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I had to set 'Greedy' = true because it was sitting inside of a droppable div.